# How to copy ms teams copilot summaries so that footnote links are still clickable?

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-copilot

Copilot (in MS Teams) will summerize a meeting and includes footnotes to the transcript/video.

But if you copy those, the footnotes lose their hyperlinks.

Is there any way to retain the hyperlinks when copying, to Word for example?

[image]